# How to convert API response of FileResult into pdf file in angular 4?

Tags: c#, angular, rxjs

I'm having a C# API with the following return type.

```
return File(result, "application/pdf");
```

How can I use this returned value in Angular 4 side and convert it to pdf?

I'm calling my C# API via http post method.

How can we download a byte array response into pdf in angular side?

Answer (score 0):

Since the content type is set as `application/pdf`, 
The same javascript method [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) can be used in Angular to download the file result.

```
public download(downloadUrl: string): void {
    window.open(downloadUrl, '_blank');
}
```

### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-download)